# ssh to a remove host and use emacs in the ssh session, cursor always move to the beginning of the screen when save file

Tags: cursor, saving

I have a VPS server and I always ssh to it and us emacs in the ssh session. I found that when I save a buffer the cursor always move to the beginning of the screen. How to disable this behavior? I don't want cursor movement when save a file.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: FWIW my initial *guess* is that you have some custom `before/after-save-hook` routine(s) causing this.